# How to group results by values that are inside json array in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column of type jSONB that have data like this:

column name: used_filters

row number 1 example:

```json
{ "categories" : ["economic", "Social"], "tags": ["world" ,"eco-friendly"] }
```

row number 2 example:

```json
{ "categories" : ["economic"], "tags": ["eco-friendly"] , "keywords" : ["2050"] }
```

I want to group the result to get the most frequent value for each one of the keys
something like this:

| key | most_freq |
| --- | --- |
| category | economic |
| tags | eco-friendly |
| keyword | 2050 |

the keys are not constant and could be something other than the example I said but I know that they will be frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract keys and values as arrays first by using `jsonb_each`, and then unnest the generated arrays by `jsonb_array_elements_text`. The rest is classical aggregation along with sorting through the count values by window function such as

```sql
SELECT key, value
  FROM ( SELECT j.key, jj.value,  
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY j.key ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
           FROM t,
        LATERAL jsonb_each(js) AS j,
        LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(j.value) AS jj
          GROUP BY j.key, jj.value ) AS q
 WHERE rank = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0af9277634aa71404d67b199ca705a74)</kbd>